# why does is 'this' the DomWindow object when executing the google maps directions service callback

Tags: javascript, google-maps, this

so I have an object defined like so (simplified):

```
mapRoute : {
            isInit : false,
            latLang : "",
            directionsService :  null,
            directionsRenderer : null,

            init : function() {
                if(!this.isInit) {
                    this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
                    this.directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
                    this.directionsRenderer.setPanel(document.getElementById("google_route_results"));
                    this.isInit = true;
                }
            },  


            planRoute : function() {
                var from;
                var to;

                from = $('#addressFrom').val();
                to = this.LatLang;

                var directionsRequest = {
                    origin:from,
                    destination:to,
                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                };

                this.directionsService.route(directionsRequest, this.planRouteCallback);
            },

            planRouteCallback : function(result,status){
                if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    this.directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
                    this.directionsRenderer.setMap(google_map_object);
                } else {
                    this.handleErrors(status);
                }
            },

            //handleErrors
            handleErrors : function(statusCode) {
                //do stuff
            },


        }//end mapRoute
```

however, when my planRouteCallback execute, I get errors because 'this' refers to the DomWindow object, not my mapRoute object.  why is this the case, and is there anything I can do about it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the function is being executed not from within the context of the `mapRoute` object. So for example:

```
var foo = {bar: 10, fn: function(){ alert(this.bar); }};
foo.fn(); // called within the context of the object foo, so it alerts 10

var noContextFn = foo.fn;
noContextFn(); // uh oh, no context, alerts undefined
```

When you pass your callback `mapRoute.planRouteCallback` to other functions, they now have a reference to the right functions, but won't execute that callback in the context of `mapRoute`, just as above.

You could create an anonymous function and use the self=this pattern every time you pass the callbacks as parameters, although you're probably better off fixing the function itself up once and for all.
You can bind the function. After the `mapRoute` object has been built, you can run:

`mapRoute.planRouteCallback = mapRoute.planRouteCallback.bind(mapRoute);`

(Note, `bind()` might not be implemented in all browsers, see [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for an implementation you can use).

Answer (score 1):

First, "this" in javascript is a bit tricky and depends on where the function was called, not just where it was defined.

The quickest cross browser solution is to use a closure. Google actually has a great article on closures with google maps here.

http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/events.html#Event_Closures

You have access to the GEvent.bind method, which you could use to reference your call back correctly.

```
 GEvent.bind(map, "click", myCounter, myCounter.increment);
```

But I don't know how to implement that with direction route. Also, it may be deprecated with v2. Here is a better link to the maps v3

http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html

So, maybe consider something like this:

```
 var directionsRequest = {
                origin:from,
                destination:to,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            };

 var that = this;
 var planRouteCallback = function(result,status){
            if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                that.directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
                that.directionsRenderer.setMap(google_map_object);
            } else {
                that.handleErrors(status);
            }
        },

 this.directionsService.route(directionsRequest, planRouteCallback);
```

Simple closures really help with callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using jQuery's proxy to get the results I wanted

```
this.directionsService.route(directionsRequest, $.proxy( this.planRouteCallback,this));
```